# dc.js: Tooltip does not display

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js, dc.js

I'm making a graph using the Dimensional Charting javascript library dc.js, which is based on d3 and crossfilter. i am new in dc.js library.i am trying to display the graph using django framework for python.i am trying to display the  styling tooltip but cant display.i am trying following code.

```
       {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
       {% block content %}
     <head>
    <link href="{% static 'css/dc.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
           <div class="container" style="margin-top: 140px">

           <div class="col-lg-4" id="test">

           </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4" id="test1">

            </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/d3.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/crossfilter.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="{% static 'js/dc.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
     var spenderRowChart = dc.rowChart("#test1");

     d3.csv("{% static 'sampledata/pramod.csv' %}", function(error, experiments) {

      experiments.forEach(function(x) {
       x.Name = x.Name;
        x.Party = x.Party;
        x.Gender = x.Gender;



      });

      var ndx  = crossfilter(experiments),

      GenderDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Gender;});
      spendPerName = GenderDimension.group();
      PartyDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Party;});
      PartyPerName= PartyDimension.group().reduceCount();


      // tooltips for row chart
      var tip = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function (d) { return "<span style='color: #f0027f'>" +  d.key + "</span> : "  + numberFormat(d.value); });
      chart
        .width(200)
        .height(200)
        .dimension(GenderDimension)
        .group(spendPerName)
        .innerRadius(50);

      spenderRowChart
        .width(350).height(900)
        .dimension(PartyDimension)
        .group(PartyPerName)
        .label(function (d) { return d.key })
        .title(function (d) { return d.value })
        .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value })
        .elasticX(true);

      chart.render();
      spenderRowChart.render();

      d3.selectAll("#test1").call(tip);
            d3.selectAll("#test1").on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide);


    });

    </script>
            </body>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tooltips are built-in to dc.js as .title properties on a chart object.
Try something like this on the chart object:

```
.title(function(d) {return d.key + 
    " £" + currFormat(d3.round(d.value)) + 
    " (" + d3.round((d.value / d3.sum(siteqtysum.all(),
     function(d){ return d.value;}))*100,1) +"%)";})
```

This will generated a tooltip against a row that says e.g. `'London £1234 37.3%'`
You can add text `"\n"` in the title to get a linefeed in the tooltip.